# How to display images and info using scroll view and pageController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I want to display some images in UIScrollView and with pageViewController because every image will have different information from the other so now I'm able to do that but I want to display the info at the same time when I change the image, I mean when I change the photo to another I want to display the other photo and the info about that photo, the info that I want to display in code is an array named "labelList" and the images that I display named as imageList.

```
class PremiosViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
    let imagelist = ["img_1", "img_2", "img_3"]
    let labelList = ["label_1", "label_2", "label_3"]

    var scrollView = UIScrollView()

    var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: 250, width: 200, height: 50))

    var yPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat=0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 270, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
        configurePageControl()

        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        for  i in stride(from: 0, to: imagelist.count, by: 1) {
            var frame = CGRect.zero
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
            frame.origin.y = -100
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
            self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

            let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: imagelist[i])!
            let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
            myImageView.image = myImage
            myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
            myImageView.frame = frame

            scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imagelist.count), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("changePage:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("changePage:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func configurePageControl() {
        // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagelist.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

    }

    // MARK : TO CHANGE WHILE CLICKING ON PAGE CONTROL
    func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
        let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x,y :0), animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func clickBackButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: similar to the way you add a UIImageView to the scrollview, can't you add a UILabel as well?

Comment: Well, I tried to but I can make it yet.

Answer (score 2):

If want to display the info in just a `UILabel`, then you can do it in a similar approach as to how you have added your multiple `UIImageView`, you can add a `UILabel` as well

For example in your code where you have written:

```
let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: imagelist[i])!
let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
myImageView.image = myImage
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
myImageView.frame = frame

// TODO: I added this here

scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
```

I have added a `TODO` comment there just to show you where you can add your `UILabel` also by doing:

```
let myLabel = UILabel();
myLabel.text = labelList[i]
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
var labelFrame = CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: frame.size.height - 100, width: frame.size.width, height: 100)
myLabel.frame = labelFrame
```

and below your code line `scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)` you can then add your `UILabel` as well:

```
scrollView.addSubview(myLabel)
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now, I apply your example and it's working properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView to show images and information inside UICllectionViewCell with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Yes I thought that but in the app design is not like that so I have to adapt the code. :(